# Trouble with Wordpress 'Sobre' theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, background-image

I am editing a purchased wordpress theme ('Sobre') for a friend and am having trouble with the background image to display. On the content-page.php the code reads:

```
$bg_image = sobre_get_post_option($queried_object_id, 'page_heading_bg/url', $default_value = null);
```

To which I've changed/replaced with:

```
$bg_image = sobre_get_post_option($queried_object_id, '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/img1.jpg', $default_value = null);
```

When I live preview I continue to see a grey background. When I view the source code that line of code is missing. Any thing I can try/do differently?

Comment: `<?php` you are already in side a php block, so this makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

you dont start `<?php`, again, when you are already writing in php, im going to guess this is actually what you want:

```
$bg_image = sobre_get_post_option($queried_object_id, get_template_directory_uri().'/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/img1.jpg', $default_value = null);
```